# how can i move barcode scanner to next product

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I wanted to generate a barcode in the type of PDF417 with combination for two barcodes.For this i tried to combine the barcodes with the carriage return separator.

D=985604001200000003146892725609%0d98560112256036530331642239

But if i scan with barcode scanner it is not recognising the second barcode number,scanner is terminating with only one barcode number.

Some body please help what need to add in my string,so that scanner will move to the next product,so that scanner will read the both the barcodes.

here is the link which i am using to generate barcode image.

http://www.bcgen.com/demo/IDAutomationStreamingPDF417.aspx?ECL=0&D=985604001200000003146892725609%0d98560112256036530331642239&MODE=Binary&PT=T&X=0.03&O=0&LM=0.2&ROWS=0&COL=0&TRN=0&XYR=3&MAE=F&MAF=0&MAS=0&MAL=F

Comment: please explain more, the barcode scanner read form pdf file?!

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer,no PDF417 is barcode type..

Comment: oh, okay you want to read two bar codes in a single barcode image in one time?

Comment: yes....exactly i am looking read two bar codes in a single barcode image in one time

Comment: i think it is impossible; cause the barcode is unique. but you can make intermediate bar code that indicate to the both original bardoes, you need to save in a database that information (ex: 0001 and 0002 have the one code bar 0003, in your application when you got 0003, you will search in the db table where the id is 0003 you will find 0001 and 0002).

Comment: how can we interact with data base if scanner doing scan,that's not possible i believe.

Comment: no you can do that, but the way is base on the problem kind that you are handling. for example stock products managments. in the textbox that the scanned typing the code the scanner when finishing reading will do an event 'Enter down' you will take the text fro text box and looking in your database and retrieve the target product and do your stuff with.

Comment: sorry you can store more data in this kind of barcode. sorry i googled about, so you have a problem my in the using of the data coding, try to use an other separator.

Comment: what represents the data that you want to store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Guys here is the answer i found after lot of research,It will help to most of the guys who are unaware about this and who are trying to close the question.

if we use ~013 which is ascii value for carrier return.